# Auto generate year based on future date

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format, strtotime

I have a date string formatted as `March 8 - 10` where the year is not provided, but based on the current day of the calendar year, this would be dates in March of the next year.

What is best approach to provide the accurate year when a date given similar to the above is past Dec 31?

Thinking something like below using `$sdate > $now` however this would add +1 year to any date greater than now and not consider Dec 31 as the end of current year.

```
$dates = trim('March 8 - 10');
$now = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("now"));

    if (strpos($dates,'-') !== false) {
            $sdate = trim(substr($dates, 0, strpos($dates, '-')));

            if ($sdate > $now) {
                $sdate = strtotime("+1 year", strtotime($sdate));
                $sdate = date("Y-m-d", $sdate);
            }

            $month = substr($sdate, 0, strpos($sdate, ' '));
            $edate = $month.substr($dates, -2, strpos($dates, '-'));
            $edate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($edate));
        }
```

Comment: Interesting question, I'll work a bit on it and post my answer.

Comment: In this case you're just using `March 8`, right ?

Comment: March 8 would be the reference point for the start date.  So if we took today, I would like to show March 8 2016.  Or 2016-03-08  The assumption being that March 8 is occurring in 2016 since today is Oct

Comment: I just don't know how to reference Dec 31 being the end of 2015 so if a date is past this point it should show 2016 as the year

Comment: Can we assume that, if the provided date if older than the current date, is next year ?

Comment: Not entirely. For example, if the date provided is Nov 4, that is technically past the current date of today, but not in 2016.  This is where I keep running into the problem.

Comment: "**Nov 4, that is technically past the current date of today**"  I'm not following you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

#### Example:

```
$in = trim('March 8 - 10');

$now = new DateTimeImmutable(); // Defaults to now
$start = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('F j+', $in); // Parse month and day, ignore the rest

if ($now > $start) {
    $start = $start->modify("next year");
}

$end = $start->setDate(
    $start->format('Y'),               // $start year
    $start->format('n'),               // $start month
    substr($in, strrpos($in, ' ') + 1) // trailing bit of $in for day
);

echo $start->format("Y-m-d"), "\n";
echo $end->format("Y-m-d");
```

#### Output

```
2016-03-08
2016-03-10
```

Given a string like `'November 8 - 10'` it'll output:

```
2015-11-08
2015-11-10
```

Comment: Just realized DateTimeImmutable is not valid in PHP 5.3 - would I use DateTime for use in 5.3? Doing so doesnt work as you have above.  What would you suggest?  This solution works perfectly in 5.6

Comment: Thanks Paul - I will look into upgrading PHP in general and will use your edits here.  Really appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$input = 'December 8 - 10';
//$input = 'August 8 - 10'; //un-comment to test past date (next year)
$inputFormated = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'F j+', $input.date("Y") );
$now = new DateTime( 'NOW' );
if( $now > $inputFormated ){
   $inputFormated->modify( '+1 Year' );
   echo $inputFormated->format( 'Y-m-d' );
}else{
   echo  $inputFormated->format( 'Y-m-d' );
}
```

---

`December 8 - 10` -> `2015-12-08`

`August 8 - 10` -> `2016-08-08`

---

DEMO:

https://eval.in/449346

Answer (score 1):

An naive solution perhaps

```
$reference = time ();
$ts = strtotime ('03-08');
if ($ts < $reference)
  $ts += strtotime ('+1 year') - $reference;
$result = date ('Y-m-d', $ts);
```